# Active directory and firewalls

Tags: firewall, active-directory

I am not familiar with active directory and have very limited knowledge of firewalls.  I am trying to understand how 'trusts' work.  Say there is a situation like the following:

1. There are 2 separate networks
2. An external trust is to be given to a domain in network1 to another domain in network2

Wouldn't the users in domain in network1 need go past the firewall in network2 first? How does the set up work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, traffic would have to be allowed between the two networks, but its less clients and more AD servers that need to exchange domain related data. remember trust is a cryptographic construct, so it has nothing really to do with firewalls. I would recommend that you use some form of tunneled connection (VPN, SSH, etc) to enable inter-lan communication though, since there is danger in exposing those linkages across the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about establishing a trust over the internet - don't do that.  Use something like AD Federated Services for that.

But I assume you are not talking about establishing an AD trust across the internet and instead are just talking about traversing internal firewalls on your networks.

[This article lays it out exactly.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756944%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) View the link or open this image in a new tab to view full size:

[image: Trusts]

So basically you just want the same ports you want for a member server to authenticate with an AD. A DC uses the same ports to establish a trust with another DC. Kerberos, LDAP, etc. etc.

Of course you need name resolution too.  That's usually handled with a stub zone or conditional forwarder in DomainA that allows it to resolve DomainB.

For RPC, [you can restrict the dynamic RPC range](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596) of your computers via the registry. If you don't like opening 10,000 ports for dynamic RPC across your firewall, you can at least restrict it to a few hundred dynamic ports.